# How do i start a particle system in for example frame 80?

Tags: animation, keyframes, fire

I am making a fire extinguisher that spits out fire. and idont want the fire to start at frame 1

Comment: When rendering simply choose frame 80 as first frame of the rendered animation.

Comment: *Particle Properties > Emission > Frame Start / End*

Comment: Particle Properties > Emission > Frame Start / End Thank you HISEROD

Comment: set Frame start and end in particle setting